# IFrame print not showing text on Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, printing, custom-font

I have an `iframe` inside an HTML (code shown below). When i try to `print` the `iframe` apart from the dotted line nothing appears in the `print` (This is specifically happening for `Google Chrome`, on `Firefox` it works properly).
I am using `custom fonts`.
Here's the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv() {
 var browser = get_browser_info();
 window.document.getElementById('print_frame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML;
 if((browser.name=="MSIE" || browser.name=="msie" || browser.name=="IE" || browser.name=="ie")) {
  window.document.getElementById('print_frame').contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
 }else{
  window.document.getElementById('print_frame').contentWindow.focus();
  window.document.getElementById('print_frame').contentWindow.print();
 }
 window.document.getElementById('print_frame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
 return false;
}
function get_browser_info(){
 var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
 if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
  tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
  return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
 }   
 if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
  tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
  if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
 }   
 M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
 if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
 return {
  name: M[0],
  version: M[1]
 };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="modal" style="display: none;">
  <style type="text/css">
@font-face {
 font-family: ROsans;
 src: url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.eot?) format('embedded-opentype'),
  url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.woff) format('opentype'),
  url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.svg#filename) format('svg'),
  url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.ttf) format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: ROsans;
 src: url(ROsanswebtextbold.eot?) format('embedded-opentype'),
  url(ROsanswebtextbold.woff) format('opentype'),
  url(ROsanswebtextbold.ttf) format('truetype');
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: normal;
}
</style>
  <div
   style="width: 100%; font-family: ROsans, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;">
   <h4 style="font-size: 0.8em;">This is H4</h4>
   <br> <br> <span style="font-size: 2em; padding-top: 2px;">This
    is First Span</span> <br>
   <div
    style="border-top-width: 4px; border-top-style: dotted; border-top-color: #000; padding-top: 10px">
    <table style="width: 100%; background-color: #fff;">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 30%; font-size: 0.8em;">First TD</td>
       <td style="width: 70%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.8em;">second
        TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="font-size: 0.8em;">third TD</td>
       <td style="font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold;">fourth TD</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="font-size: 0.8em;">fifth TD</td>
       <td style="font-size: 0.8em;">sixth TD</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <iframe title="myIframe" id="print_frame" name="print_frame" width="0"
  height="0" style="display: none;"></iframe>
 <Button id="iframeGen" onclick="printDiv();">Generate</Button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this stylesheet code.
This should work for you.

```
src: url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.eot?) format('embedded-opentype')
```

This line from your code seems to be causing the issue.

```css
    <style>
@font-face {
                font-family: ROsans;
                src: url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.eot') format("eot"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.woff) format("opentype"),                
    url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.svg#filename) format("svg"),
                url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype");
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
                font-family: ROsans;
                src: url(ROsanswebtextbold.eot') format("eot"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextbold.woff) format("opentype"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextbold.ttf) format("truetype");
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: normal;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This just stops the error, but the print does not have the correct font.
The font i get after print is Times New Roman/Calibri

Answer (score 0):

```css
    <style>
@font-face {
                font-family: ROsans;
                src: url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.eot') format("eot"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.woff) format("opentype"),                
    url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.svg#filename) format("svg"),
                url(ROsanswebtextregular-webfont.ttf) format("truetype");
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
                font-family: ROsans;
                src: url(ROsanswebtextbold.eot') format("eot"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextbold.woff) format("opentype"), 
    url(ROsanswebtextbold.ttf) format("truetype");
                font-weight: bold;
                font-style: normal;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Hi @DeepakKumar, welcome to Stack Overflow. Here we care about good questions and good answers, always trying to go beyond just code to highlight how it works with explanations. Take a look at the [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide.